# jquery auto add a tag on link with dedicated URL part

Tags: jquery, url, lightbox, colorbox

I want to use a lightbox clone (colorbox) feature on images in my CMS.
The CMS uses TinyMCE 4 as Wysiwyg editor.

To use the lightbox feature, I have to add a "rel='xyz'" tag to the full image link around my thumbnail shown.

Unfortunately, in TinyMCE editor the end user can not add a "rel" tag ... except in source code editor.
An alternative would be to use a small jquery code to assign such a "rel" tag on document ready, like ...

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".myClass").colorbox({rel:'image_group'});
...
```

This would do the job theoretically, unfortunately the user can not enter the class on a link either in the gui (and to go to add it in the source code view is a NoGo for them!).

What the end user can enter in link gui is the link URL, a titel & a target and the text/thumbnail to be shown.

On the site, I have images of 2 different sources, a template folder and a media folder. Luckily, I want to use the lightbox effect on all the images of the media folder. But of course not of those from the template.

Therefore, after user edit, I have following saved:

```
<p>
<a title="image1" href="http://my.url.ch/media/image1_big.jpg"><img src="http://my.url.ch/media/image1_small.jpg" alt="image1" width="300" height="300" /></a>
<br />
<a title="image2" href="http://my.url.ch/media/image2_big.jpg"><img src="http://my.url.ch/media/image2_small.jpg" alt="image2" width="300" height="300" /></a>
</p>
```

And what I need when page is shown to visitor is:

```
<p>
<a rel="colorbox" title="image1" href="http://my.url.ch/media/image1_big.jpg"><img src="http://my.url.ch/media/image1_small.jpg" alt="image1" width="300" height="300" /></a>
<br />
<a rel="colorbox" title="image2" href="http://my.url.ch/media/image2_big.jpg"><img src="http://my.url.ch/media/image2_small.jpg" alt="image2" width="300" height="300" /></a>
</p>
```

(to be very precise: the place where this rel attribute is added doesn't matter ;-)  )

Now the question: Is it possible to add the "rel" tag on document ready (like in code above) but on all `<a>` tags coming from a dedicated URL part only (e.g. the media folder) ?
And if yes ;-) can someone also please provide a tip how ...

Thx a lot

Comment: after the user submits whatever is in the TinyMCE Box you display that content like a  blog? and it is there you want to add rel tag for all images of media folder?

Comment: Hi Rohit, yes exactly. But only for images out of the media folder (these are those the user has selected).

Comment: see i think you should add it before the user submits it so that you can get the value in the database too

Comment: Unfortunately this is not working as I would need to change then the CMS core ....

Comment: can you please post a couple of exact html tags that you need to alter.

Comment: html examples added in original question above

Comment: ok it can be don just creating a pen for the same..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am adding another answer due the reason that the OP cannot access CMS's code without which my previous answer gets nulled. but I am leaving the answer for other people as it works under normal circumstances. with that said here is the new answer.

This piece of code will find all the tags with `<a>` element and add `rel="colorbox"` if the href contains *"/media/"* text.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.each($('a'), function(index, element){
    if(element.toString().indexOf("/media/") > 0){
      $(this).attr('rel', 'colorbox');
    }
  });
});
```

http://codepen.io/Rohithzr/pen/JXryRp

check the pen above for working example. It is using below code as html where two elements have */media/* while one has */notmedia/*

```
<p>
<a title="image1" href="http://my.url.ch/media/image1_big.jpg"><img src="http://my.url.ch/media/image1_small.jpg" alt="image1" width="300" height="300" /></a>
<br />
<a title="image2" href="http://my.url.ch/media/image2_big.jpg"><img src="http://my.url.ch/media/image2_small.jpg" alt="image2" width="300" height="300" /></a>
<a title="image2" href="http://my.url.ch/notmedia/image2_big.jpg"><img src="http://my.url.ch/notmedia/image2_small.jpg" alt="image2" width="300" height="300" /></a>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

could something like this work?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.each($('img'), function(index, element){
    var img = $(element);
    //match the img tags, which src attribute starts with //i. only.
    if(img.attr('src').match(/\/\/i\..+/)){
      img.attr('rel', 'something');
    }
  });
})
```

you would just change the regular expression to match the url of your images.

https://jsfiddle.net/j0vmcqa2/

[UPDATE]

You also need to have in mind, that I am checking the img tags, in your case I think you need to add it to a tags. The idea is simillar, you can can change 'img' with 'a' and instead of searching in the src attribute you would do it in the href attribute.

Comment: That sounds good, I will give it a try. Let you know by tomorrow.

Comment: I do not get it running ...
$(document).ready(function()
{
 $.each($('a'), function(index, element)
 {
  var anc = $(element);
  {
   if(anc.attr('href').match(/http:\/\/my\.url\.ch\/media/))
   {
    anc.attr('rel', 'colorbox');
   }
  }
 });
});`

Get an error saying: TypeError anc.attr(...) is undefined.

I also tried with $(anc) but get same error.

Comment: Getting more nuts ... When modifing your jsfiddle accordingly it work. On my site it's saying the error. PHP is 5.6, jquery is 2.1.4

Comment: The jsfiddle runs automatically, just inspect the images html code (using chrome or something similar) and you should see that the first and last image have the rel attribute equal to 'something'.

Comment: Yes, I see this in jsfiddle. I can even adapt it to <a> tag with my URL and it works in jsfiddle. But copy/paste then the source on my template it does not work the same!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this right before submitting the data to server

```
$('#form').submit(function(eventObj) {
    var content = $('#contentBox').val();
    alert(content);
    content = content.replace('<img', '<img rel="lightframe"');
    alert(content);
    $('#contentBox').val(content)
    return true;
});
```

Please verify the same and let me know at
http://codepen.io/Rohithzr/pen/bprKER
I believe the best method will be to add it when user posts it.. 
use this script when user submits so that it get dded to the database directly

Comment: Thanks for suggestion but I can not change the CMS core, which I would need to do in order to implement the above.